# Is "evening" an adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adverbs, parts-of-speech

What is part of speech of "evening" in sentences below?

```
1. She meets her friends every evening.
2. She met her friends yesterday evening.
```

I find that evening is only a noun or a adjective instead of a adverb from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/evening).

Comment: Why do you not think that "noun" is the answer?

Comment: *Every evening* and *yesterday evening* are here adverb phrases. (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evening)

Comment: @mahmudkoya Thanks for your quoting. Forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your explanation and helping me again :)

Comment: @AndyT Probably because idiot entries like [the one in Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evening), say it is an adverb in such sentences.  (See the entry below the noun one. And then weep/laugh) The best thing the OP could learn here is [not to trust dictionaries on parts of speech](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635).

Comment: @mahmudkoya No, they aren't.  They are noun phrases! :) [It's never a good idea to use a dictionary for parts of speech!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635).

Comment: @AndyT A noun can not modify a verb. But I find that "Every evening" is as an adverb phrase from koya's comment :)

Comment: @BigShield - Didn't you already say that 3 hours ago? Anyway, why do you think "evening" is modifying "to meet"? It's not.  "*I went to the park yesterday*" - do you think "park" is modifying "to go" here?

Comment: @AndyT I just want to correct the grammar in my original comment and I didn't find the button for updating comment, so I deleted it and added a new one. I am sorry to bother you.

Comment: I'm afraid that Mahmud is wrong: an adverb phrase has an adverb as head word, e.g. "quite separately from the others". But "every evening" is a noun phrase with the noun "evening" as head, and the determinative "every" as determiner. It's function is that of adjunct, these are often called adverbials which causes endless confusion.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, as described in my nifty answer below ;)

Comment: @Araucaria Ah yes. I keyed in my comment earlier, but only just got around to sending it, without spotting you answer. Btw, I don't think many people realise that NPs can be modifiers in clause structure, e.g. "Ed arrives this evening".

Comment: @BiilJ Further, Many dictionaries say even the plural form *evenings* can be an adverb. ( OLD https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evenings)

Comment: @BillJ If I ask a couple of questions to get the OP's sentences  as answers like *When does she meet her friends?*/ *How often does she meet her friends?* and *When did she meet her friends?*, would the answers to *when?* and *How often* be adverbs or not?////You had commented here, the word *evening* was a noun and even it has *evenings* as plural. I didn't say it is never noun. I said it functions here as adverbs.

Comment: Mahmud, the OP asked what part of speech "evening" belongs to. It's a noun, not an adverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, dictionaries are not very good at grammar (that's not what they're meant to be good at!). The [Collins entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/evening) is correct; the word *evening* is a noun in each case here. However, Oxford Dictionaries Online classify *evening* as an adverb in phrases such as [*every evening*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evening) (if following the link, scroll down to the 'adverb' definition and examples). The Oxford online entry, unfortunately, is incorrect.

Some dictionaries confuse the grammatical relations of a word, or a phrase it occurs in, with its part of speech. Here the word *evening* is a noun functioning as Head of a noun phrase. This noun phrase is an Adjunct (or Modifier) - it's an extra piece of information added onto the sentence. Some people call Adjuncts *Adverbials* (it is important to remember that an adverbial is not an adverb!!!). Bad dictionary entries tend to call every word that occurs in an Adjunct an adverb. This is not a good thing to do. It isn't accurate and it doesn't help learners.

We can see that *every evening* is a noun phrase, and  *evening* a noun, for several reasons:

**1.  We can use it as a Subject, or Object**

- Every evening is special here.
- I hated every evening.

**2. *Every* is a determinative which only occurs in noun phrases**

- Every dog
- *Every beautifully (ungrammatical - *every* with adverb)

**3. We can use the plural form of *evening* in similar phrases**

- We went there every evening
- We went there some evening**s**

Nouns inflect for number and are singular and plural. English adverbs don't inflect for number and cannot be singular or plural.

**4. We can use an adjective to modify *evening***

- We went there every quiet evening
- *We went there every quietly evening (ungrammatical  - adverb as modifier of *evening*)

We use adjectives to modify nouns. We have to use adverbs to modify adverbs. We cannot use adjectives:

- She danced extremely beautifully
- *She danced extreme beautifully (ungrammatical - adjective modifying adverb)

In short then, *evening* is a noun, not an adverb when it occurs in phrases such as *every evening*. The other thing to learn here is that [we shouldn't rely on dictionaries for accurate grammar information](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635)!

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I read it slowly. So can I say that the noun phrase "every evening" in my example is as an adverbial?

Comment: @BigShield You're welcome. Yes, that's right  (I don't personally like the term *Adverbial*! I prefer *Adjunct*, but that's just me).

Comment: +1 Nice one! I prefer adjunct too -- I think we agreed on that over on SE Linguistics some time ago.